# Display devanagari characters

Tags: character-encoding, display, characters, character-composition

Running Emacs 25 on Kubuntu 17.10.

I am able to enter text in devanagari script but it does not dispaly correctly in the editor.

For instance, the text entered as:

क का कि की कु कू के कै को कौ कं कः

shows as:

[image: screenshot of devanagari text]

As I `M-x describe-character`, the characters displayed correctly describe the correct character. The characters displayed incorrectly describe the base character क. Also, as I execute describe-character command, the right part of the display disappears and remains blank till I move the pointer across all characters. Then as the pointer moves across characters, the corresponding part appears on the right.

[image: correctly described character]

[image: incorrectly described character]

Comment: Very strange, part of the characters in the right side of screen? The text is correctly displayed for me (emacs 25.1.1).  Have you checked with emacs -Q (I doubt it would change that, but...)

Comment: What's reported by `M-x describe-char` with point at one of composed characters?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 I have updated the question with two more screenshots

Comment: Does the font used display those chars correctly outside Emacs? This sounds like poor support for those chars by the font you're using (just a guess).

Comment: @Drew I have the following line in ~/.emacs. `(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:family "Noto Mono" :foundry "GOOG" :slant normal :weight normal :height 143 :width normal)))))

Comment: @Drew No, I tried switching my font to a font that I routinely use for editing text in devenagari (Gargi) in other programs. It is not a monospace font. The change did take effect but the display was exactly the same (in a different font, though). Will you please try this? And let me know if it works?

Comment: @Drew Some more research done. I finally found a font (Lohit Devanagari) that displays the characters correctly. So, it was, indeed a font problem. Will you place your comment as a reply? I will, then, accept it.

Comment: Done...............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the font you are using probably does not display those characters well.  (Does it work well when you use it outside Emacs?)

Try using a different font.